# How do you use Javascript constructor methods in a jQuery statement?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't figure out how to use a Javascript constructor method in a jQuery .click method. I'm trying to get a button's function to change dynamically based on a constructor. Here's the set up:

```
<button onclick="">
</button>
```

needs to call a method that changes depending on another button. The following is my broken code:

```
    function GloveMode (name , array) {

        this.colorArray = array;

        this.displaySettings = function(){

            //Title
            $("#displayTitle").text(this.name);
            //Display Color Set
            $("#displayColors").empty();


            //Totally Broken
            $("#upArrow").click( function(){

                addColor();

            }); 

        };

        this.addColor = function(){

            console.log(this.colorArray.length);

        };
    };
```

I can't figure out how to get $("#upArrow").click() to call this.colorArray properly, or how to call this.addColor() in the .click() method! Please help.

Comment: var self = this;
 self.addColor() { ... }

Comment: This is where the prototyping aspect of JavaScript comes into play. In theory, you'll want `GloveMode` to be an entity that contains properties and methods for accessing those properties (if applicable). It should not contain global click handlers though. For instance if you want the click handler to have access to your name property then you'd use `GloveMode.name` to access the property and return it to the click handler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Problem is that "this" means something different in each function body. So save the wanted "this" to a variable e.g. "self" and use that.

```
function GloveMode (name , array) 
{
    var self = this;
    this.colorArray = array;
    this.displaySettings = function()
    {
      //Title
      $("#displayTitle").text(this.name);
      //Display Color Set

      $("#displayColors").empty();

      //Totally Broken
      $("#upArrow").click( function()
      {
         self.addColor();
      }); 

    };

    this.addColor = function()
    {
       console.log(self.colorArray.length);
    };
};
```

Comment: Thank you. I don't understand why a variable representing 'this' needs to be used here, does anybody know why?

Comment: Because you defined a function represented by the member variable `this.addColor` without a name (an anonymous function declaration). So you can reference this function only by the member variable `this.addColor`. If you would have given the function a name like `function addClass()...` then, you would have been able to access it as you did in your code example.